# Is there a definitive list of actionable items related to breaking changes for MongoDB node native driver when updating from 3.2.7 to 4.1.4?

Tags: mongodb, express, node-mongodb-native

I have upgraded MongoDB Node native driver from `3.2.7` to `4.1.4`.

I am finding the implications of this one error at a time and adjusting both server-side code (for example, different properties are now returned for things like `insertOne` and `updateOne`) and the front-end code that also relied on these returned properties for conditional handling of results.

I have referred to the official upgrade guide here:

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/HEAD/docs/CHANGES_4.0.0.md

It mentions:

> Our CRUD operations now return the drivers-wide spec-compliant results which are defined here:
> [CRUD SPEC Write Results](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/crud/crud.rst#write-results)

That link *seems* to provide generic information about categories of results, which I cannot yet map in my mind to the relevant node native driver methods that I have used.

Can anyone suggest a methodical approach to going through lots of code (~10,000 lines) and updating the relevant methods?

Is there a definitive list of methods effected?

So that I could search for each effected method in my code and update accordingly?

For reference, I have also looked at the changelog here:

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/4.0/HISTORY.md

and searched for `'breaking'`, however I cannot translate what is listed into actionable items I can perform:

```
4.0.0-beta.6 (2021-07-01)
⚠ BREAKING CHANGES
NODE-3291: Standardize error representation in the driver (#2824)
NODE-3272: emit correct event type when SRV Polling (#2825)
remove strict/callback mode from Db.collection helper (#2817)

4.0.0-beta.4 (2021-05-18)
⚠ BREAKING CHANGES
NODE-1812: replace returnOriginal with returnDocument option (#2803)
NODE-3157: update find and modify interfaces for 4.0 (#2799)
NODE-2978: remove deprecated bulk ops (#2794)

4.0.0-beta.2 (2021-03-16)
⚠ BREAKING CHANGES
remove deprecated items (#2740)
remove enums in favor of const objects (#2741)

4.0.0-beta.0 (2021-01-19)
⚠ BREAKING CHANGES
Clarify empty BulkOperation error message (#2697)
db: suppress Db events (#2251)
Integrate MongoOptions parser into driver (#2680)
bulk: add collation to FindOperators (#2679)
remove top-level write concern options (#2642)
CreateIndexOp returns string, CreateIndexesOp returns array (#2666)
conform CRUD result types to specification (#2651)
remove deprecated Collection.group helper
Options object precedence over URI options (#2691)
adds async iterator for custom promises
format sort in cursor and in sort builder (#2573)
remove Cursor#transformStream
remove deprecated find options
pull CursorStream out of Cursor
remove deprecated GridFS API
only store topology on MongoClient (#2594)
```

Thinking out loud, is it just a matter of searching my code for all instances of `collection.` and then checking each attached method's documentation, ie:

| method | 3.2 docs | 4.1 docs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| deleteOne | [link](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#deleteOne) | [link](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html#deleteOne) |
| find | [link](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#find) | [link](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html#find) |
| findOne | [link](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#findOne) | [link](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html#findOne) |
| findOneAndUpdate | [link](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) | [link](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) |
| insertOne | [link](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#insertOne) | [link](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html#insertOne) |
| updateMany | [link](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#updateMany) | [link](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html#updateMany) |
| updateOne | [link](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#updateOne) | [link](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html#updateOne) |

Comment: tried creating a branch and try the upgrades?